# Account sdk in corda

Tags: corda

Dependencies of account sdk is not getting downloaded completely. 
Error in corda-lib-dev.

https://ci-artifactory.corda.r3cev.com/artifactory/corda-lib-dev/com/r3/corda/lib/accounts/accounts-workflows/1.0-RC04/accounts-workflows-1.0-RC04.pom
I also checked this above link. It is showing 409 error.

Comment: I recommend that you avoid using release candidates (like `RC-04` in your case); instead, use `1.0` (without `-RC04`).

Answer (score 0):

`corda-lib-dev` is a snapshot repo and CorDapp developers should not be developing against these.

Releases and release candidates will be available in corda-lib going forward.

Avoid using release candidates however. 
For account, kindly use `corda-lib`, and develop again release `1.0`.